# GetStream Multiple Feed Instances of same group per user?

Tags: getstream-io

Is it possible to create multiple feeds of a feed group s.t. users can join multiple feeds of the same feed group? Specifically, we would like to create a game feed view all players in the game can see updates and post reactions/comments. Players can be part of multiple games and each game feed should be separate from any other. Is this possible using getstream and what would be the best approach?

From reading the documentation, it seems that one cannot use API to dynamically create feed groups. However, I think it should be possible to create multiple feeds of the same feed group but in their documentation (https://getstream.github.io/react-native-activity-feed/#flatfeed) it seems to suggest that we just pass the feed group and user id, which makes me think we can only create a feed per feed group per user?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it's possible.

For example, `game:game-id` and users can have their own feeds too `user:user-id`.

Comment: When I attemp such method, i get permisson errors, I can only see my own feed and can only post to my own feed. How can I achieve this? (I'm trying to create groups that users can post to and follow)

Comment: If group membership is dynamic, you need to proxy requests through your server. Otherewise, contact support to get your app permissions updated.